# ggplot error: breaks and labels are different lengths

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a graph that is similar to a population pyramid. Here is my data:

```
value  percent     party
 -5     0.02    Conservative
 -4     0.44    Conservative
 -3     7.71    Conservative
 -2     24.02   Conservative
 -1     12.17   Conservative
  1     19.77   Conservative
  2     27.17   Conservative
  3     7.36    Conservative
  4     1.05    Conservative
  5     0.26    Conservative
 -5     0.04    Labour
 -4     0.57    Labour
 -3     9.49    Labour
 -2     29.38   Labour
 -1     13.82   Labour
  1     16.99   Labour
  2     22.74   Labour
  3     5.93    Labour
  4     0.87    Labour
  5     0.19    Labour
```

The code for the graph was working the other day, here it is:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(pos_neg_data_final, aes(x = value, y = percent, fill = Party)) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(pos_neg_data_final, Party == "Conservative"), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_bar(data = subset(pos_neg_data_final, Party == "Labour"), stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5), name = "Value") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Percent", labels = abs(pretty(pos_neg_data_final$percent))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = group.colours, name = "Party", labels = c("Conservative", "Labour"))
```

And here is the graph it produced:

[image]

I want to go back and make it look nicer, add a title etc. but now the same code is giving the following error:

```
Error: Breaks and labels are different lengths
```

I have attempted to add different labels and limits, but still the same error. Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Provide example data. Run your code line by line, find out at which step you hit the error. Then compare sizes of breaks and labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code that works:

```
df=read.table(text = 'value  percent     Party
-5     -0.02    Conservative
-4     -0.44    Conservative
-3     -7.71    Conservative
-2     -24.02   Conservative
-1     -12.17   Conservative
1     -19.77   Conservative
2     -27.17   Conservative
3     -7.36    Conservative
4     -1.05    Conservative
5     -0.26    Conservative
-5     0.04    Labour
-4     0.57    Labour
-3     9.49    Labour
-2     29.38   Labour
-1     13.82   Labour
1     16.99   Labour
2     22.74   Labour
3     5.93    Labour
4     0.87    Labour
5     0.19    Labour',header=T)

group.colours = c('blue','red')
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = value, y = percent, fill = Party)) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(df, Party == "Conservative"), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_bar(data = subset(df, Party == "Labour"), stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5), name = "Value") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Percent", labels = abs(pretty(df$percent))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = group.colours, name = "Party", labels = c("Conservative", "Labour"))
```

The issue was that the percent value were not negatives for conservative I think.

Output :

[image]

Lemme know if it was was you wanted

Comment: Thank you! It was the negatives for the Conservative data. Such a simple mistake.